# Grails Scaffold Save Fails Silently

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am just working with a new little prototype project and am attempting to load data using the scaffold feature.  I go through the save process, it says it has saved on the UI after but then I revisit and the list of objects is still at 0.  I added

```
loggingSql: true
```

into my .yml but I see no sql statements.

```
class RiUser {

    String firstName
    String lastName

    static hasMany = [riCases: RiCase]
    static constraints = {

    }
}


class RiUserController {
    static scaffold = RiUser
    def index() { }
}
```

[Adding RiUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Les.png)

[UI shows no RiUsers After Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8GDr.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the @Transactional annotation to the controller.

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
@Transactional
class RiUserController { 
    static scaffold = RiUser
    def index() { }
}
```

NOTE: This is an "ok" approach if you're just getting started with Grails, but in a real-world application you'll want to avoid scaffolding and implement the controller methods yourself. You can use `grails generate-controller <entity>` to get a jump start on default scaffolded implementation.

Your controller methods should delegate to your service layer which will handle any persistence-related activities. The service layer methods will be wrapped in transactions by default so you won't have to worry about annotating those method unless you want to control the propagation level and/or whether the methods are read-only, which you can read more about in the docs.

http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html#declarativeTransactions

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response and thank you.  Still not saving it though....you know of any way to drill down and find an error message?